# Ошибка при создании связей

Tags: php, mysql

[image: таблицы mysql]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь настроить связи между таблицами, чтобы при удалении или обновлении изменялись столбцы, связанные внешним ключом, но сталкиваюсь с ошибкой. Как я понял здесь ссылки не несуществующие сообщения, но как тогда спроектировать базу данных?
Заранее большое спасибо

Comment: если мне не изменяет память, то в mysql запрещено удаление полей имеющих атрибут "Внешний ключ". Для удаления записи вам сначала требуется удалить строку содержащую ключ и лишь потом потомка.

Как мне кажется для большинства мелких проектов не стоит устанавливать связи, большинство целей достигаются хорошо составленными запросами типа SELECT,UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT и тд.

Comment: Даже не знаю, собеседовался с разработчиками и они спросили есть ли связи. И я решил практиковаться. Но спасибо за наводку

Comment: UPD: разобрался с проблемой. Сейчас у меня внешний ключ от chatMessage к data, а был наоборот

Comment: пароли в базе не хранят, если что...

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, вы уверены? )) А как же добавление соли и шифрование?

Comment: @Quazimorda, тогда это "хэш и соль", а "adfsgs" на скриншоте на хэш не похож

Comment: Тогда следует уточнить, что в базе не принято хранить пароли как есть, в незашифрованном виде. Да, я зануда )) С подобной поправкой ваш комментарий был бы корректнее ))

Comment: Я и не хранил) все вверху захешированные, а "adfsgs" я в навикете для теста связей руками добавил